How to Implement Server Redirection with Authorization in a React App Using Apache?
I need help with server redirection in my React app. My app runs on an Apache web server. I’ve tested redirection with this PHP code:
(redirect.php)
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    $url = "/";
    header("Location: $url");
    exit;
?>

(index.html)
<form id="redirectForm" action="https://.../redirect.php">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

Redirection works fine in a simple HTML form. But in my React app, I need the following:

Authorization Header: I must send an authorization header with the request.
POST Method: The request must use the POST method.
No Visible Form: Using a hidden form with inputs could work, but it doesn't handle the authorization header.

I want to avoid client-side redirection. For example, I know I could check the response, and if the status code is 302, get the new location from the header and redirect the client manually. However, I think this is not secure enough. This is especially important because I'm redirecting to a payment gateway, which needs to be handled very carefully.
How can I achieve this in a React app? Any advice or examples would be very helpful.
this is what I have implemented in my react app
const apiUrl = "https://.../serverRedirect.php";

const paymentRedirect = ({ token, body }) => {
    fetch(apiUrl, {
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
        headers: {
            // I tried "application/json" in the front-end and the back-end too
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
        method: "POST",
    });
};

export default paymentRedirect;

